# Login problem in stackoverflow in chrome as “Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled”

Tags: support, bug, login, cookies

There are lots of question related the same. But none of them helped me to get rid of this error “Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled”.

I get the answer as my sytem time is wrong  from that questions. Yes my sytem time was wrong at first.

But after I corrected the system time, still the error persists in Chrome 23.

The Firefox 17 is working fine for me.

Comment: What does it say when you visit http://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help/ ?

Comment: @AndrewC Cookies failed, rest are ok.

Comment: I think it's a misleading error message, and should say "unable to set cookie from openid.stackexchange.com", because as far as I can tell, that's the problem, and I don't like to enable third party cookies willy-nilly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put this in the answer too: check at https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help  to see how stackoverflow feels about your browser settings.

I was having exactly the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

### Go to settings

[image: Right hand side of page, three horizontal bars, settings is near the bottom]

### Scroll down and choose to see advanced settings.

[image: +Show advanced settings]

### Scroll down a bit to Privacy settings and click Content Settings

[image: Content Settings]

### Click Manage exceptions

[image: Manage exceptions]

### Make sure the necessary stackexchange sites are listed

The syntax of the Hostname Pattern field uses square brackets in my view needlessly `[*.]`, but ho hum. You could add

```
[*.]stackauth.com          # needed: to support autologin (broken in my Chrome)
openid.stackexchange.com   # needed: this sent you the third party cookie
[*.]stackoverflow.com      # my favourite
[*.]meta.stackoverflow.com # just to be super sure 
[*.]stackexchange.com      # for those other interesting founts of knowledge
```

[image: Allow Allow Allow Allow]

Comment: [Nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)!

Comment: As an aside, wouldn't "Keep local data only until I quit my browser" make life easier? (It would require you to quit your browser every now and then. And it won't solve the third-party cookie issue, I know.)

Comment: @Arjan Do you mean instead of blocking third party cookies? If so, no. Here's how it goes with me: if I trust you, you can have a cookie. If I don't trust you you can't. If I use you a lot (multiple times a week), your cookie can stay permanently, if not, it's gotta go when I quit the browser. Third party cookies just don't fit with my attitude to cookies. Stackexchange is the _only_ place I've wanted to allow them. Uniquely it's a network of intercommunicating different domains where I feel at home. Not even my employers's different domains deserve third party cookies.

Comment: Quitting my browser every now and then wouldn't stop an ad network building up a partial profile. If they want to make money out of my data, tough.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to 3rd party cookies, but to 1st party data, in *"Block sites from setting any data"*. Just so you understand (which I guess you do): how often does your IP address change while not quitting your browser? And you know [just blocking explicit data isn't enough](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), right?